# How to wait for the execution of an associated file to complete?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to run the associated file `blah.png` and wait for it's completion prior to continuing from within a batch/cmd file.

Using `start /wait blah.exe` waits for the execution of the executable file to terminate, but when I use `start /wait blah.png`, the `/wait` is ignored.

Is there away around this?

Comment: How does a .png file complete? It's an image.

Comment: @SomethingDark The application that got executed to show the `.png` completes.

Comment: What if no application was launched to show the `.png`? For example, the `.png` may be displayed by an existing Web browser. No new application was launched. Instead, an already-running program was asked to open the image.

Comment: `start /wait test.png` works as intended for me (using IrfanView). (also `start /w test.txt` works fine with notepad)

Comment: Not really a solution for any use case but can you not just use "start /wait <program that should open png> blah.png" if this is just fo a specific scenario with one batch file? Most programs would open a file given as command line parameter

Comment: @Syberdoor: Yeah, that is how I do it now, but I wanted to know if it was possible to do this with the default viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, just find the name of the process. when the process is running %ERRORLEVEL% will be "0" when the process is finished %ERRORLEVEL% will change to "1" and the loop will end.
Add the below in after `start blah.png`

```
 :loop
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('tasklist ^| find "TaskName.exe"' ) do (
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
        ping -n 10 localhost > nul 2>nul
        goto loop
    )
)
```